# C# Asynchronously read data from a redirected StandardOutput

Tags: c#, asynchronous, redirectstandardoutput

I'm developing a C# WFA that allows me to do some stuff with a chemistry software: GAMESS.

Basically I have a batch file that when executed with appropriate arguments return a file with the data needed for atomic analysis.

In my app form I've set up a read-only textbox with the output of the process. I've done this by redirecting the Standard Output. This read is done in a synchronous way. Works well for small outputs but many time the lines weel exeedes 240k. My process automatically closes when ended (last instruction is "EXIT", not "EXIT /B").

As you have (probably) figured out the main form becomes unstable and don't allow any user input until the process ended. This is a problem...

I've tried asynchronous read of a FileStream for a different function in my code and worked wery well but I'm stuck for what concerns the StandardOutput. I can't figure out the right way to do it.

Here my code so far:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Input_job_file) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Log_file))
            {
                textBox3.Text = "Executing code...\r\n";
                string outtext;
                string batpath = string.Format(Settings.Default.path_to_gamess + "\\rungms.bat");
                string arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} 0 {3}", Input_job_file, Settings.Default.version, Ncpus, Log_file);
                //Here we need to copy the input file to the gamess directory in order to avoid errors
                File.Copy(Input_job_file, Settings.Default.path_to_gamess + "\\" + FileNameWithoutExtension + ".inp");
                Process gamessjob = new Process();
                gamessjob.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
                gamessjob.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                gamessjob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                gamessjob.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                gamessjob.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                gamessjob.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                gamessjob.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Settings.Default.path_to_gamess;
                gamessjob.StartInfo.FileName = batpath;
                gamessjob.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments; //input_file, version, number_of_processors, "0", output_name]
                gamessjob.Start();

            //STDOUT redirection to our textbox in readonly mode
            outtext = gamessjob.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            textBox3.Text += outtext + "\r\nProcess executed!";

            //here we clean up some stuff after GAMESS code ends
            File.Delete(Settings.Default.path_to_gamess + "\\" + FileNameWithoutExtension + ".inp");
            MessageBox.Show("Code executed!\nCheck output for errors or messages.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Input file and/or output location is invalid!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}

//ASYNC
byte[] result;
textBox6.Text = "Executing code...\r\n\n";

using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(Input_dat_file, FileMode.Open))
{
        result = new byte[SourceStream.Length];
        await SourceStream.ReadAsync(result, 0, (int)SourceStream.Length);
}
```

Ideally reading the redirected standardoutput in async should solve the deadlock of my app (right?) or at least reduce the duration of it. Maybe if I do this with ReadLineAsync() instead of ReadToEndAsync() the textbox will update more frequently and, therefore, be more "pleasant" to see.

I've searched tutorials for async operations but all of them show file-based operations. Looking to the Microsoft reference for redirect standard output and async is confusing me even more.

Can someone help me figure out a way to read the output line by line with ReadLineAsync()?

Comment: How big is the file your dealing with, is it really that big that its causing a deadlock?  If thats the case I would think Copying the Full file and deleting it would cause a lot of trouble since you're not doing those async. Also what are you doing with the file? Do you need the whole thing or are you using it line by line. I dont even see you using the results of the file what are you doing with it?

Comment: In reality what I need is a way to get the text that the terminal would show when executing this bat file. The whole things associated with file generation and stuff is handled by the code inside the bat file itself.

Comment: The lenth of the terminal output is not under my direct controll. That's because based on what specific molecule model file iI gave to the script the output can vary. Sometime is 140 lines printed on terminal and other times is 100k+ lines.

Comment: I'm confused on what you're doing with the file,   Async frees the thread when doing operations which are non cpu intensive e.g network request/IO etc.  you state "the textbox will update more frequently and, therefore, be more "pleasant".   What do you mean by this, are you updating the text box for each line in the file? Or are you to the rendering update eg the amount of time that the gui is locked?

Comment: i think what you want is to still use ReadAsync, but you want to create a smaller buffer size, so that you're not reading the full file at once. e.g create a for loop and read in chunk instead of doing `0, (int)SourceStream.Length` you do `lastBuffer, bufferSize`

Comment: With the code above the whole text is read once (ReadToEnd) and then printed in the textbox. My plan was to update it for each line but this doesn't happen. For example: textBox3.Text = "Executing code...\r\n". This should be printed before the process starts, seems logical, but this line is shown only when the process ends.

Comment: You want to print the file line by line async ahh

Comment: Maybe I've setted up the code part for the question in a wrong way. The code after //ASYNC is an example of async read from a file that has nothing to do with the process named "gamessjob" it's only to show how I've implemented it for another part of the code. What I'm looking for is an "equivalent" way to use async in a redirected standardoutput of a terminal.

Comment: Add the code for where you're calling the async function, you only showed the sync function

Comment: You need to run your button event async e.g `public async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs 
{
      var items = await this.ReadMoleculeFile();
}`  and then just put in your async reading code in a function ReadMoleculeFile

Comment: Ok, I've tried the following and works for reading the whole output of the process. It even solved the problem about the fact that the textBox3.Text = "Executing code...\r\n" wasn't showing until process ended.    `public async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  {  outtext = await gamessjob.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();}`

Answer (score 2):

Got it. Here follows the code that works. This way the textbox will be updated line by line and the deadblock doesn't occurs anymore.

```
public async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Input_job_file) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Log_file ))
        {
            textBox3.Text = "Executing code...\r\n";
            string outtext;
            string batpath = string.Format(Settings.Default.path_to_gamess + "\\rungms.bat");
            string arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} 0 {3}", Input_job_file, Settings.Default.version, Ncpus, Log_file);
            //Here we need to copy the input file to the gamess directory in order to avoid errors
            File.Copy(Input_job_file, Settings.Default.path_to_gamess + "\\" + FileNameWithoutExtension + ".inp");
            Process gamessjob = new Process();
            gamessjob.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
            gamessjob.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            gamessjob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            gamessjob.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            gamessjob.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            gamessjob.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            gamessjob.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Settings.Default.path_to_gamess;
            gamessjob.StartInfo.FileName = batpath;
            gamessjob.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments; //input_file, version, number_of_processors, "0", output_name]
            gamessjob.Start();

            //STDOUT redirection to our textbox in readonly mode
            while((outtext = await gamessjob.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                textBox3.Text += outtext + "\r\n";
            }
            textBox3.Text += "\r\nProcess executed!";
            //here we clean up some stuff after GAMESS code ends
            File.Delete(Settings.Default.path_to_gamess + "\\" + FileNameWithoutExtension + ".inp");
            MessageBox.Show("Code executed!\nCheck output for errors or messages.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Input file and/or output location is invalid!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
```

Comment: I've added the following to prevent that: `button1.Enabled = false;` then the execution part an it follows `button1.Enabled = true;`